# There’s no one but + Verb

Tags: sentence-construction, syntax

I came across this exercise:

> There’s no one ... wishes peace.
> A. who
> B. that
> C. but

At first, I was confused with “who” and “that” as I thought both of them were correct, but then the answer turned out to be “but”. I don’t know why **who** and **that** are wrong and I need some more information about the usage of “no one but + Verb”. I’m familiar with “no one but + N”, but this is the first time I’ve seen this structure.

Comment: All three options make valid sentences, though of course one would assume that _everybody_ , rather than _nobody_, wishes for peace. Unless more information was given about the context of the sentence, it's nonsense to say that A and B are 'wrong'.

Comment: Do the options make any difference in meaning?

Comment: Yes, as I indicated. The first two mean that nobody wishes for peace, the third that everyone does. _But_ in this context means _except_ - there is no-one else except for those who wish for peace.

Comment: I’ve been looking for more information on the structure “no one but V”, but I haven’t found anything about it. I would be grateful if I can get more information about it.

Comment: _None but_ is more usual, though it's a rather old-fashioned, poetic usage. There's a saying (from a 17th century poem by Dryden) _None but the brave deserves the fair_ (only a brave man deserves a beautiful woman). See https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/not-one-but.2927774/

Comment: I already know how to use “no one but + noun”. I just want to know more about “no one but + Verb”. With regard to my given sentence, does it mean “there’s no one else except for those who wish for peace” or just simply “there’s no one who doesn’t wish for peace.”?

Comment: Surely both of those mean the same? I used the first one in my earlier comment, just to spell out exactly what _no one but_ implied. I realised after posting my last comment that _none but + noun_ was different, but the link I provided gives examples of _not one but + verb_.

Answer (score 1):

A and B are certainly correct grammar. If I was answering I'd choose A because "who"  is more often used for the relative pronoun when referring to a person.  But "that" is also used (and here you can argue logically "no one" isn't a person...)

"But" is wrong.  It is possible to use "but" as a conjunction. In that case it links two clauses.  You could say "There is no one but one who wishes peace" or "There is no one who wishes for aught but peace"  These are both formal and marked expressions, and not typical of normal writing.

The expression: "There is no one but wishes peace" is incorrect grammar.  The only way I can parse it at all is to assume that "wishes" is a plural noun which is a noun adjunct to peace, and the noun phrase "wishes peace" is a somehow a compound noun that is a type of person.

(There may be some archaic poetic uses,  Kate in a link gives "Not one but hung limp" in a poem by Frost to mean "There was not one person who did not hang limp")

A bit of googling shows that this precise phrase has found its way into some Chinese grammar studies (http://blog.sina.com.cn/s/blog_4bff2ed8010007ms.html) Nevertheless, the test is wrong, as a test of modern standard English.